# How to get really big curly braces

Tags: delimiters, size

I currently have the following equation that I would like to write:

```
\begin{equation*}
\pi(X)=\mathbf{N}_4\Bigg\{\left(\begin{matrix} 1 
\\2\\1\\3\end{matrix}\right),\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\1 & 2 & 1 & 
3\\ 2 & 1 & 3 & 3\\3 & 3 & 3 & 7\end{matrix}\right)\Bigg\}
\end{equation*}
```

But the curly brackets `\Bigg\{` and `\Bigg\}` aren't big enough - is there a way to get bigger curly brackets?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use `\left\{` and `\right\}` for the braces as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Original equation:
\begin{equation*}
  \pi(X) = \mathbf{N}_4 \Bigg\{ \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3
  \end{matrix}
  \right), \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
    3 & 3 & 3 & 7
  \end{matrix}
  \right) \Bigg\}
\end{equation*}

Updated equation:
\begin{equation*}
  \pi(X) = \mathbf{N}_4 \left\{ \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3
  \end{matrix}
  \right), \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
    3 & 3 & 3 & 7
  \end{matrix}
  \right) \right\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Colab MathJax do not understand `\left\{`. You can use `\bigg\{` instead.

Answer (score 11):

This is one of the few situations that warrants the usage of `\left` and `\right` for automatically sized delimiters.  If you want to manually size your delimiters at any cost you can easily define more sizes.  Therefore I made the factory `\makebig`.  It takes a name and a size and defines the corresponding macros and the open and close variants.

For the braced matrices you can just use `pmatrix` from the `amsmath` package.

EDIT: `amsmath` has a smarter mechanism to define new manually sized delimiters.  Thanks for pointing it out egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\makebig[2]{%
  \@xp\newcommand\@xp*\csname#1\endcsname{\bBigg@{#2}}%
  \@xp\newcommand\@xp*\csname#1l\endcsname{\@xp\mathopen\csname#1\endcsname}%
  \@xp\newcommand\@xp*\csname#1r\endcsname{\@xp\mathclose\csname#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\makebig{biggg} {3.0}
\makebig{Biggg} {3.5}
\makebig{bigggg}{4.0}
\makebig{Bigggg}{4.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \pi(X) = \mathbf{N}_4 \biggggl\{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 3
  \end{pmatrix},
  \begin{pmatrix}
      2 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
      1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
      2 & 1 & 3 & 3 \\
      3 & 3 & 3 & 7 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
  \biggggr\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]