# Reproduce a Snippet from a Japanese Learning book (using rcases?)

Tags: xetex, mathtools, border, text-manipulation, japanese

I use Anki, which supports generating LATEX images for usage during study sessions. I would like to reproduce this snippet of text:

[image: Japanese instruction image]

I have been trying to drink from the firehose that is Latex for 2 weeks now. This is the closest I can achieve:

[image: my generated image]

While these results are very much usable, I m a bit obsessive with details. The main question I have is how can I use multiline text in a math enviroment where cases are used? Note how the second two lines of the second, sub rcases centers on the braket at line 1 instead of between line 1 and line 2 being centered on the bracket.

Some auxiliary questions:

1. Is the math environment the right/most efficient way to achieve this? Am I following that right path of abusing math equations to recreate this snippet? Or is it more efficient/possible to do this without math?
2. How can I get the border around the generated block?

Below is my XeTex template. Latex is a deep and vast system. I acknowledge I am a total novice. The reason I am coming here is that I took two weeks for me to learn how to do this one thing. I have spent more time studying latex than I have spent studying Japanese. I am hoping someone can give me some pointers and I can replicate for the 60 or so other snippets I want to put in my study application.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{article}
%\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
\begin{rcases}
    \begin{rcases}
        V\\
        \text{い-adj}
    \end{rcases}\text{plain form} \\
    \begin{rcases}
        \text{な-adj}\\
        N
    \end{rcases}
         \text{
             \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
                 plain form\\
                 ～\cancel{だ}->～な
            \end{varwidth}
          }
\end{rcases}\text{んです}
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tabular nested within an array and thus avoid most `\text{....`

This code adds a border around the block using `\fbox{...}`

As an alternative it is possible to use a single tabular environment. In this example with the `nicematrix` package.

The command `\Block{<number of row-number of columns>}` acts as multicolumn/multirow simplifying the code.

In both cases it is necessary to insert the braces.

Additionally it is used a command from
[Henri Menke`s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389992/161015)  to enlarge the braces.

[image: y]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[20pt]{article}
%\special{papersize=3in,5in}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho.ttf}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage{nicematrix}%** added  <<<<<+    

% ***************From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389992/161015 Henri Menke
\makeatletter
\newcommand\makebig[2]{\@xp\newcommand\@xp*\csname#1\endcsname{\bBigg@{#2}}}
\makeatother
\makebig{Bigggg}{5.5}
% *******************************
    
\begin{document}
    
Using array/tabular\medskip 

\fbox{\bfseries% % \fbox adds a border <<<
    \begin{math}
        \begin{array}{l@{}}         
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                V\\
                い\ -adj % added a space with \ <<<<
            \end{tabular}\Bigg\}~\text{plain form} \\[3ex]
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                な\ -adj\\
                N
            \end{tabular}\Bigg\}~
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                plain form\\
                ～\cancel{だ}\textrightarrow～な % arrow <<
            \end{tabular}   
        \end{array}\Bigggg\}\text{んです}
    \end{math}
}   

\bigskip        

Using nicematrix\medskip

\fbox{\bfseries%
\begin{NiceTabular}{l @{}l@{\hspace*{0.7ex}} l @{\hspace*{0.7ex}}l@{} l@{}}[cell-space-limits = 4pt]
    V       &\Block{2-1}{$\Bigg\}$} &\Block{2-1}{plain form}&\Block{4-1}{$\Bigggg\}$}                        &\Block{4-1}{んです}\\
    い\ -adj                         &                                                                       &&\\
    な\ -adj&\Block{2-1}{$\Bigg\}$}  &\Block{2-1}{\\[-1.5ex] plain form \\ ～\cancel{だ}\textrightarrow～な}   &&\\
    N                               &                                                                        &&
    
\end{NiceTabular}}

\end{document}
```

To avoid the misalignment in the second column of your code use:

```
\text{% notice the % <<<<<
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
```