How do I put a matrix inside a linear equation that's inside brackets (with brackets as big as the matrix)?
I'm trying to make something that looks like this:

I've managed to put the matrix inside the brackets, but my problem is how to make them cover the matrix instead of being smaller.

please take a look at this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389989/how-to-get-really-big-curly-braces

This:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&a\\-a&b
    \end{pmatrix}\;\middle|\;a,b\in\mathbb R\right\}\]
\end{document}

will give this:


+1. Since the vertical bar functions as a relational rather than as a binary operator, you may want to replace \,\middle|\, with \;\middle|\;.

@Mico Good idea. Thank you.

I could rewrite it using $x$ instead of \[x\], correct? Thanks a lot for the input.

Yes, you can do it, but then I suggest that you use \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&a\\-a&b\end{smallmatrix}\right) instead of \begin{pmatrix}1&a\\-a&b\end{pmatrix}.

Here's a solution that employs a psmallmatrix environment (provided by the mathtools package).

\documentclass{article} % or some other 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'psmallmatrix' environment
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for '\mathbb' macro
\begin{document}
\[
S_1=\bigl\{ \,
\begin{psmallmatrix} 
  1 & a \\ -a & b 
\end{psmallmatrix}
\bigm\vert a,b\in\mathbb{R} 
\, \bigr\}
\]
\end{document}


I noticed in your solution that you used \bigl\{ \, instead of the usual \left\{. The syntax you use seems a bit more complicated, and thus I wondered if there was any advantages to it over the classic approach?

@Atex - Not sure what's supposed to be non-classical about using \bigl, \bigm, and \bigr. Your claim that it's more complicated than \left-\middle-\right is doubtful, as I can write \bigm\vert, as opposed to \;\middle|\;. The reason I insert \, after the opening curly brace and before the closing curly brace is not related to the use of \bigl\{ or \bigr\}. Instead, I insert the thinspaces because that's what Don Knuth does in The TeXbook, in one of the chapters on fine math typesetting. If a method is good enough for Knuth, it better be good enough for me...

Good point. Perhaps it's because I've mostly seen solutions using \left, \middle, \right, but I'm also relatively new (Used LaTeX since spring this year), and it may be that \bigl, \bigm, \bigr were popular back then and thus "the real classic"!
You also mentioned the reason you insert \, is because of someone named Knuth. Does that mean that this book is the golden standard for how to typeset your documents in LaTeX?

@Atex - Your expression "the [gold] standard for how to typeset your documents in LaTeX" is (probably unintentionally) loose: the TeXbook deals with what's called "Plain TeX", not LaTeX. (LaTeX was created by Leslie Lamport, not Don Knuth.) That said, most Plain-TeX macros are available for LaTeX users as well. BTW, you may find the example I gave above on p. 174 of The TeXbook (p. 185 in the pdf file), just a few lines above the header "EXERCISE 18.21". Regarding fine math typesetting: You can't go wrong if you fully assimilate the contents of chapters 16 thru 19 of The TeXbook.
